# ESRI ArcGIS JSAPI 3.4 Defect when setting LODS on a map. How to fix?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I tend to get better help here then the ESRI forum so...

Using http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html I was able to create a simple application which demonstrates that if you set a non-trivial lods on a map the basemap will not behave correctly (try zooming beyond level 15).

Any workarounds?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Create a Map</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=9, IE=10">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/js/esri/css/esri.css">
  <style>
    html, body, #mapDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/3.4/"></script>
  <script>
    require([
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/layers/ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer"
        ], 
        function (Map, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer) {

        var webLods = [
            //{ "level" : 0, "resolution" : 156543.033928, "scale" : 591657527.591555 },
            //{ "level" : 1, "resolution" : 78271.5169639999, "scale" : 295828763.795777 },
            //{ "level" : 2, "resolution" : 39135.7584820001, "scale" : 147914381.897889 },
            //{ "level" : 3, "resolution" : 19567.8792409999, "scale" : 73957190.948944 },
            //{ "level" : 4, "resolution" : 9783.93962049996, "scale" : 36978595.474472 },
            //{ "level" : 5, "resolution" : 4891.96981024998, "scale" : 18489297.737236 },
            { "level" : 6, "resolution" : 2445.98490512499, "scale" : 9244648.868618 },
            { "level" : 7, "resolution" : 1222.99245256249, "scale" : 4622324.434309 },
            { "level" : 8, "resolution" : 611.49622628138, "scale" : 2311162.217155 },
            { "level" : 9, "resolution" : 305.748113140558, "scale" : 1155581.108577 },
            { "level" : 10, "resolution" : 152.874056570411, "scale" : 577790.554289 },
            { "level" : 11, "resolution" : 76.4370282850732, "scale" : 288895.277144 },
            { "level" : 12, "resolution" : 38.2185141425366, "scale" : 144447.638572 },
            { "level" : 13, "resolution" : 19.1092570712683, "scale" : 72223.819286 },
            { "level" : 14, "resolution" : 9.55462853563415, "scale" : 36111.909643 },
            { "level" : 15, "resolution" : 4.77731426794937, "scale" : 18055.954822 },
            { "level" : 16, "resolution" : 2.38865713397468, "scale" : 9027.977411 },
            { "level" : 17, "resolution" : 1.19432856685505, "scale" : 4513.988705 },
            { "level" : 18, "resolution" : 0.597164283559817, "scale" : 2256.994353 },
            { "level" : 19, "resolution" : 0.298582141647617, "scale" : 1128.497176 }
        ];

     var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
        center: [-85, 35],
        zoom: 3,
        basemap: "streets",
        lods : webLods,
        slider : true,
        sliderStyle : "large"        
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
  <div id="mapDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's likely a bug here which I think we have a fix for in the next (3.5) release.

In the meantime, instead of using map.options.lods, try specifying [minZoom and maxZoom](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/map.html#MapConst) to specify the range of levels you'd like your map to use.

Comment: This works but not for ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer as a base layer...can't set LODS on a dynamic layer?  Setting both the map lods and the minZoom resolves this for dynamic and tiles layers.

Comment: For a map with only dynamic layers, you'll have to use LODs. I've confirmed we've fixed this at 3.5 (due out in the next couple of days).